# Power (Laurent) Series of $\coth(x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need some help to prove that the power series of $\coth x$ is:

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^3}{45} + O(x^5) \ \ \ \ \ $$

I don't know how to derive this, should I divide the expansion of $\cosh(x)$ by the expansion of $\sinh(x)$? (I've tried but without good results :( )

Or I have to use residue calculus?

Anyone can suggest me a link where I can find a detailed explanation of this expansion?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find the Taylor series of $x*\mathrm{coth}(x)$ by taking derivatives, and divide by $x$

Comment: You should be able to adapt the approach [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=5YBwrzrYk2kC&pg=PA176), by an appropriate change of variables...

Comment: Divide series for cosh by series for sinh, yes that works.  You need to remember "long division" to apply this, however...

Comment: @GEdgar But... Do I have to make the long division between the expansion of cosh and sinh without truncate them?

Comment: Yes, just as you divide infinite decimals "without truncate them"... At each step you use only finitely many terms.

Comment: @GEdgar ok I think that I don't know how to do that XD can you give me a link to similar examples? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long division.

The problem:
[image: z8]
Now $z$ into $1$ is $z^{-1}$
[image: z7]
Multiply
[image: z6]
Subtract
[image: z5]
$z$ into $(1/3)z^2$ is $(1/3) z$
[image: z4]
Multiply
[image: z3]
Subtract
[image: z2]
$z$ into $(-1/45)z^4$
[image: z1]
If we want more terms in the quotent, we will have to fill in more terms in all of them where the dots are now.

Comment: Ok you are too kind.. thanks, I've made some stupid mistake in the division:(

Answer (score 5):

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \coth(x) &=& \frac{\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)} = \frac{1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^5\right)}{x + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^5\right)} = \frac{1}{x} \frac{1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^5\right)}{1 + \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right)} \\ &=&  
  \frac{1}{x}  \left( 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^5\right) \right) \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{7 x^4}{360} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right) \right) \\ &=& 
  \frac{1}{x} \left( 1 + \frac{x^2}{3} - \frac{x^4}{45} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right) \right) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^3}{45} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^3\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where the reciprocation and multiplication of series used:
$$
 \frac{1}{1 + a x^2 + b x^4 + \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right)} = 1  -a x^2 + \left( a^2-b \right) x^4 + \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right)
$$
$$
  \left( 1 + a x^2 + b x^4 +  \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right) \right) \left( 1 + c x^2 + d x^4 \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right) \right) = 1 + \left(a+c\right) x^2 + \left(b + d + a c\right) x^4 + \mathcal{o}\left(x^4\right)
$$

---

The result for the reciprocation is obtained using the geometric series:
$$
    \frac{1}{1-w} = 1 + w + w^2 + \mathcal{o}(w^2)
$$
Now substitute in the above $w = a x^2 + b x^4 + \mathcal{o}(x^4)$, and use $$w^2 = \left( a x^2 + b x^4 + \mathcal{o}(x^4) \right)^2 = a^2 x^4 + \mathcal{o}(x^4)$$

Comment: OMG, thanks Sasha... how did you know that reciprocation? Do you have simply found it looking for a polynomial that multiplied by 1+ax^2+bx^4+o(x^4) gives you back 1 ?

Comment: @MaJac89 I have filled in steps of computing the reciprocal.

Comment: thanks for the further explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Long division of series with $\cosh(x) = 1 + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^4}{24} + \ldots$
and $\sinh(x) = x + \dfrac{x^3}{6} + \dfrac{x^5}{120} + \ldots$.  Unfortunately I don't know how to typeset this nicely in LaTeX.

First term is $1/x$, 
$$1 + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^4}{24} + \ldots - \dfrac{1}{x} \left(x + \dfrac{x^3}{6} + \dfrac{x^5}{120} + \ldots\right) = \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^4}{30} + \ldots$$
Next term is $x/3$,
...