# Finding a Laurent series when denominator contains an infinite series

Tags: laurent-series

I'm looking for the Laurent series around $x=0$ of a particularly resilient function.

$$f(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\tag{1}$$

A.k.a. $f(x) = \text{coth}(x)$. I have found the first two terms—which was all I needed really—but the method I used generalised very poorly if I were to look for more terms. And wouldn't work at all if I was looking for the exact solution.

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n (x)^n\tag{2}$$

I have looked at my book on complex analysis. First, it is mostly concerned about weather a solution exist, and not so much, how to find it. Second, in the way it does discuss finding solutions, I am recommended rewriting the expression in terms of known series expansions, and reverse-engineer the solution using relations like the following.

$$\frac{1}{1-Y} = 1 + Y^2 + Y^3 + \cdots \;\;\;\; ; \;\;\;\; |Y|<1 \tag{3}$$

But I haven't found any way to rewrite equation $(1)$, in forms like the one in equation $(3)$. The problem is mainly that I don't know how to deal with the infinite series in the denominator.

$$
f(x) = 
\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\tag{4} =
\frac{\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\cdots\right) + 
\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}
{\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\cdots\right) -
\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}
$$

Any solution that I have found begins by chopping the denominator at some suitable length. But then I will never reach the exact solution like in equation $(2)$. Right?

PS. In my original problem $x$ is a real number, so I used $x$ instead of $z$. But anyway..

Comment: See (6) and (7) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicCotangent.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find a _method_ for finding the solution at this link.

Comment: maybe try from $f'=1-f^2$ and identify the coefficients.

Comment: Unless you are hoping for endless recursion, the generating function for the Bernoulli Numbers is the way to get a closed form.

Comment: If you are familiar with a method @paul, quit building suspense and tell us all about it! Or perhaps you have some link to a good source-material dealing with a problem like this?

Comment: For a [division way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167149/power-laurent-series-of-cothx), for a [closed form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html), following from (29) and (30), the last one requiring knowledge about the Bernoulli Numbers and their definition in terms of a generating function.